# React Native cancel Redux action

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have an action file where i have created an action (It calls a service for data). Also, i have a reducer file where i declare the action type.

In my component, i am importing this action, binding it to the props and using it. (ex: `this.props.useThisSpecificAction`)

At some point the user may leave the page while the call is still being made and once the response is received, it will cause the yellow warning of updating state on an unmounted component.

I've read the cancel promise but i couldn't find my way implementing it.

This is a sample of my action:

```
export const useThisSpecificAction = (value1,value2) => ({
  type: USE_THIS_SPECIFIC_ACTION,
  payload:ActionCoordinator.useThisSpecificAction(value1, value2)
// i am calling the web service in the payload
});
```

Any help is highly appreciated and thanks all in advance.

Comment: I've come across the same problem. Why don't you read this article https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html . At the bottom there is a section about cancelling promises.

Comment: I already found that article, i just tried to implement it with no success. If you got my files structure above, how do you think the implementation should be?
- actions/action.js
- reducers/reducer.js
- components/someComponent/index.js

in Index.js i am calling this action this.props.useThisSpecificAction(()=> { }).then((response) => { /* Here i am updating the state */  });   on componentDidMount, and i keep calling it every few seconds (for business reasons). @nbkhope any ideas?